# Which flag do I apply if someone is asking the same question again?

Tags: discussion, flags, duplicate-questions

I recently saw someone ask a Question again. I want to flag it as a duplicate of the previous question, but the previous question does not have an accepted or upvoted Answer. So which flag should I use on this question?

**Question asked today:** [PercentRelativeLayout only displaying API 23](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38352383/percentrelativelayout-only-displaying-api-23)

**Question asked 9 days ago:** 
[PercentRelativeLayout okay on Emulator, not okay on phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38173828/percentrelativelayout-okay-on-emulator-not-okay-on-phone)

Answer (score 12):

Mark the question as a duplicate.  The lack of an upvoted answer is irrelevant in such a case: The accepted/upvoted answer rule doesn't apply for duplicates by the *same user*.